# Kivy: Why does ListView declare differently in .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

Making a slight alteration to [list_simple_in_kv.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/lists/list_simple_in_kv.py) to use [ListAdapter](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.listadapter.html) instead of `SimpleListAdapter`, i find that Method #1 works:

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

#using 'sla'...whatever that means...
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview
#:import sla kivy.adapters.listadapter

<ListViewModal>:
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            sla.ListAdapter(
            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
            cls=ListItemButton.ListItemButton)
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainView(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 1
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        listview_modal = ListViewModal()

        self.add_widget(listview_modal)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MainView()
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

But changing the kv file to this way (the way that's most in-line with the other kv API's i've come across) fails:

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter

<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        ListAdapter:
            data: ["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)]
            cls: ListItemButton.ListItemButton
""")
```

I even came across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/kivy-users/dBV2fOf7NP4) post, and [this one too](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/862), saying that method #2 should work in master, but it yeilds an Exception:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\adapters\adapter.py", line 102, in __init__
     raise Exception('adapter: input must include data argument')
 Exception: adapter: input must include data argument
```

What am i missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sla` are the initials from `SimpleListAdapter`, but in your case it is `ListAdapter` since you change the import on the top `#:import sla kivy.adapters.listadapter`. I am also editing your post because I think there is an indentation mistake

Comment: @toto_tico: You're right about the indenting. Thanks.

Comment: @toto_tico, I've rejected your edit. If you want to correct a syntactic indentation error in his Python code. You must post it as an answer, not edit the question, otherwise this will confuse people who look at this question later.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I would have agreed with you but the working code was copy & past incorrectly. Indeed, NoobSaibot accepted that I was right about his indentation in the code that **was supposedly working**. It is not related to the answer, just format.

Comment: @toto_tico, Sorry, I made a mistake then. It looks like someone else agreed with you and reverted my rejection. However, it does look that you lost credit for your edit. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListAdapter is not a Widget so you cannot use the syntaxes you are attempting to use. I think the nearest you can do to achieve a more Kivyonic appearance to the code is the following. Notice I change the imports. This looks similar to the way you add instructions to a canvas:

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)], cls = ListItemButton)
""")
```

** Edit **

You also changed the `size_hint`, so the previous code looks very different from the original. This one looks as the original.

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<ListViewModal>:
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)], cls = ListItemButton)
""")
```

Comment: "List Adapter is not a Widget..." I wonder why...Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Because the Widgets are components you add hierarchically to the graphic user interface. The `Widget` `ListView` could work with different type of data estrutures through his adapter property. `ListAdapter` is just another [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that change data structure the Widget is able to work with

Comment: I'm just saying, that shouldn't be the case. Kv file is *awesome* because it makes things so much simpler. It shouldn't have monkey-wrenches like this...How do i bring this up to the Kivy "higher-ups"?

Comment: I guess you can create an issue in (github)[https://github.com/kivy/kivy]. Also, the user @tshirtman in stackoverflow is part of their team. I offered him a bounty and answer one of my questions.

Comment: I still don't think it is an inconsistency, though. As far as I know, Kivy language provides support for Widgets and canvas instructions. Another example similar to the `adapter` case, would be the transitions of the [ScreenManager](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#changing-transition). I can see a couple of differences: widgets and instructions are related to gui ([view-controller model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) and you add multiple Widgets and Instructions but just one adapter/transition.

Comment: To be fair, i'm not sure what the vision of the Kivy developers is. I just feel like the end-result should be *coding in Kv, customizing in python*. The hierarchical layout of the kv language is very good. Imagine using kv language to completely outline your application, and then customizing as needed in python classes. If that's not their goal, then i withdraw. I just see potential here.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, there is two parts here. First, would you like to specify the parameters of any constructor in Kv (adapter case)? Second, would you like all the attributes of any class?. In both cases the code look prettier. The first case doesn't contribute to what we already can do (the `adapter` can be added after all). The second case would be interesting because, as you said, would let you create the class structure. You should open an issue in github or fork the project and try to include the parsing yourself. This [line](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/lang.py#L1142)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this answer but you are not adding anything to the `adapter` property. Try this:

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter

<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            ListAdapter.ListAdapter:
                data: ["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)]
                cls: ListItemButton.ListItemButton
""")
```

I agree that sla.ListAdapter is not clear. Usually we have access to the class directly. Tell me if this works:

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            ListAdapter:
                data: ["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)]
                cls: ListItemButton
""")
```

Notice that I change the imports of `ListItemButton` and `ListAdapter`.

Comment: No dice...got an error: `Invalid indentation (too many levels)`.

Comment: sorry I missed one blank space on the last indentation level, I put 3 instead of 4... the error is duplicated in both attempts of answer.

Comment: @NoobSaibot, I know why :D. List Adapter is not a Widget! So, you cannot use that syntaxes. The most similar to that you can get is using sort of the canvas syntaxes, so it looks more kivyonic. I ll post it in a sec.

Comment: I posted another question. That works for me but it changes the appearence. I don't know why.